# <audio> tag in bookdown documents

Tags: html, bookdown

I have tags such as this interspersed in one of my bookdown chapters:

```
<audio class="audio-specs" controls src="my.mp3"></audio>
```

When I run a regular RMarkdown html report the auto players are inserted at the right spots.  When I run bookdown all of them float to the first page.

Suggestions for keeping them where they belong are welcomed.

**Update**: Some of my  tags may be too close to section headers and so are included in the table of contents.   I can solve this problem but I'm encountering several other html customizations that seem to not work with bookdown.

Comment: I don't know where you inserted this tag, but per documentation at https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/usage.html, you should not insert anything before chapter headers. If you inserted `<audio>` after a chapter header, **bookdown** shouldn't move it (if it did, it is probably a bug, and we'll need a reproducible example).

Comment: I'm finding that for adding a number of `html` customizations the result is better if I use the regular rendering to `html` output using output method `bookdown::html_document2` rather than `Build`.